# Laravel 4 NotFoundHttpException controller routing why?

Tags: php, hyperlink, controller, routes, laravel-4

I'm trying to make a link work in laravel 4, the link is:

```
<a href="NieuweTaak">Nieuwe taak</a>
```

This link will result in

```
laravel/ToDo/public/NieuweTaak
```

My routing is:

```
Route::get('NieuweTaak', 'showView@NieuweTaakController');
```

My controller:

```
class NieuweProductController extends BaseController{


public function showView()
{
    return View::make('newTask');
}
```

}

But somehow when i click the link it gives a NotFoundHTTP exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is `NieuweProductController`, while your rout says `NieuweTaakController`

I think you should correct it to (or change the class name):

```
Route::get('NieuweTaak', 'NieuweProductController@showView');
```

Btw, action goes **after** the controller name, it's `className@method`